# I'm getting the time picker value in 24 hr format. How can I convert it to 12 hr format?

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker

Code

```
    public static class TimePicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
//            displayCurrentTime.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + " : " + String.valueOf(minute));
            displayCurrentTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d %s", hourOfDay == 0 ? 12 : hourOfDay,
                    minute, hourOfDay < 12 ? "am" : "pm"));
        }
    }
```

This is the code that I'm using to display the time from the time picker. But the time is being displayed in `24hr format` because of `is24HourFormat`.
 How do I convert the same into `12hr format`?

Comment: Search questions before you post them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
  @Override
public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
    String dateIn12Hour=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    displayCurrentTime.setText(dateIn12Hour);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setIs24HourView` method of `TimePicker` and set it to false.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView(java.lang.Boolean)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by-

```
Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddReminder.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                eReminderTime.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
            }
        }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time  //false if 12 hour
        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();

    }
});
```